# Select ... in equivalent in JPA2 criteria

Tags: jpa, criteria, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

Is there any way to perform a query like the following using JPA2 criteria APIs?

```
select a from b where a in (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

There's a way to do that using plain Hibernate, but we can't find anything like that in JPA2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes JPA 2 Critera supports returning a specific field from a entity and using a where clause which includes an `in` clause.  I have included an example below which takes a JPQL and converts it to a similar JPA 2 Criteria-based option.

JPQL:

```
select b.a from B b where a in (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Criteria:

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
// assuming a is an Integer  
// if returning multiple fields, look into using a Tuple 
//    or specifying the return type as an Object or Object[]
CriteriaQuery<Integer.class> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Integer.class);
Root<B.class> from = query.from(Bean.class);
query.select(from.get("a"))
     .where(from.get("a").in(1, 2, 3, 4));

// create query and execute...
...
```

Here are some links that give some addition examples of using `in`:

- [Pro JPA 2: mastering the Java Persistence API](http://books.google.com/books?id=j84hdeHH2PYC&lpg=PA261&ots=C-LgrMeOC-&dq=jpa2%20criteriabuilder%20%2b%22.in%28%22&pg=PA261#v=onepage&q&f=false)
- [eAltuure Blog](http://www.altuure.com/2010/09/23/jpa-criteria-api-by-samples-part-i/)

Hope this helps!