# Select … not in equivalent in JPA2 criteria

Tags: jpa, criteria, criteria-api

Is there any way to perform a query like the following using JPA2 criteria APIs?

```
select a from b where a not in (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705291/select-in-equivalent-in-jpa2-criteria), this is the inverse.

Comment: Look at the JavaDoc: [CriteriaBuilder#not()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#not%28javax.persistence.criteria.Expression%29)

Comment: Please close the question. Also try to combine two bad questions in a single one, that reflects more exact your problem (I mean your newer questions). Thanks.